# At what shops can I return an old TV that I intend to throw away in Japan?

Tags: japan, electrical-goods, recycling

I have purchased a TV set in Japan. I am now preparing to move back abroad where I will have no use of the TV (and no way to transport it). I tried selling it to a second hand shop, but they would not accept it as it is older than 10 years.

It seems that throwing away a TV using one’s city’s rubbish collection is as much of a hassle and the preferred way is to return it to the place where you bought it for recycling by the producer (I gathered as much after calling the city hall). However, this specific shop is quite a bit away *and* is a second-hand shop too (albeit one specialising in electronics).

Could I instead return a TV to any other shop that sells TVs? If so, are there any restrictions (e.g. should the shop sell the same brand of TVs)? Will I have to persuade the shop to take it or will it do so happily? There is an Edi-On not too far away from me that I would use if this is an option.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to bring a TV (and probably similar larger electronic devices) to electronics chains (e.g. Edi-On) for recycling. The only questions I was asked at the counter was whether I had a point card and then my address.

Online, they post prices a customer has to pay to bring a TV in for recycling. However, to my surprise I was not charged. I wonder if this means that the chain sold this exact model ten years back and thus considers it to be one of ‘its own’.

The entire experience was hassle-free, worked with minimal Japanese and I was done in 15 minutes.